# SSRS sum if series expression error

Tags: reporting-services, expression, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-gp

I'm working with Microsoft dynamics GP, trying to get some data to display in a column chart in SSRS. Below is the query I used to get started

```
SELECT RTRIM(S.CUSTNMBR) 'Customer ID', RTRIM(C.CUSTNAME) 'Customer Name', S.SOPTYPE, 
CONVERT(varchar(4), YEAR(S.DOCDATE)) +' Q'+ convert(varchar(1), DATEPART("QUARTER",S.DOCDATE)) AS 'YEAR QUARTER',
S.DOCDATE, S.DOCID,SL.QUANTITY
FROM SOP30200 S INNER JOIN SOP30300 SL ON S.SOPNUMBE = SL.SOPNUMBE
INNER JOIN IV00101 IV ON SL.ITEMNMBR = IV.ITEMNMBR
INNER JOIN RM00101 C ON S.CUSTNMBR = C.CUSTNMBR
WHERE S.VOIDSTTS = 0 AND IV.ITMCLSCD NOT IN ('NON INV','TRAINING','LABOR')
```

In the series properties in SSRS I've added the following to the value field.

```
=SUM(iif(Fields!SOPTYPE.Value = 3 AND Fields!DOCID.Value = "INV" 
OR Fields!DOCID.Value = "RMAINV", Fields!QUANTITY.Value, 0))
```

When I preview the report there's no data in the chart.  For the chart I'm just using a column chart.  Any ideas?

Additional Information: 
To clarify my above statement.  The expression used is for the values in the chart data.  When I right click on the columns in design mode, I get the option to select series properties.

Link to picture for the data points I'm working with on the chart. [Chart Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGQaJ.png)

Query I used to confirm the expression:

```
SELECT RTRIM(S.CUSTNMBR) 'Customer ID', RTRIM(C.CUSTNAME) 'Customer Name', CONVERT(varchar(4), YEAR(S.DOCDATE)) +' Q'+ convert(varchar(1), DATEPART("QUARTER",S.DOCDATE)) AS 'YEAR QUARTER',
SUM(iif(S.SOPTYPE = 3 AND S.DOCID = 'INV' OR S.DOCID = 'RMAINV', SL.QUANTITY, 0)) 'QUANTITY'
FROM SOP30200 S INNER JOIN SOP30300 SL ON S.SOPNUMBE = SL.SOPNUMBE
INNER JOIN IV00101 IV ON SL.ITEMNMBR = IV.ITEMNMBR
INNER JOIN RM00101 C ON S.CUSTNMBR = C.CUSTNMBR
WHERE S.VOIDSTTS = 0 AND IV.ITMCLSCD NOT IN ('NON INV','TRAINING','LABOR')
GROUP BY S.CUSTNMBR, C.CUSTNAME, CONVERT(varchar(4),YEAR(S.DOCDATE)) +' Q'+ convert(varchar(1), DATEPART("QUARTER",S.DOCDATE))
```

Edit : format code

Comment: Have you already confirmed that you do get results if you add those 3 conditions to this query?

Comment: Yes, when I query this in SSMS I receive data.  I chose not to format the query this way so I'll have better flexibility to build multiple charts from one query.

Comment: Sounds like it's just an issue with how you created the chart. Make sure you add to the `Values` section for the chart, not just `Series Groups`. Other than that, I think we would need more information about the report design to determine what's wrong.

Comment: StevenWhite, I've updated the original post to explain myself further.  Hope that help clarify some things.  The design is really simple at this point.  It's just the query and trying to have the query display data based on the Year and quarter which I've formatted to one column.  Display some sales quantity and group them in the chart by the year and quarter.  I just don't see why the expression doesn't return the any values when it display in a sql query.

Answer (score 1):

After StevenWhite asked some questions, it started to get me thinking differently about my problem.
So instead on just relying on the chart I added a table to display the data.  And it was returning data, but a data value of 0.  Therefore I wasn't getting any values returned on my chart.  I had made the mistake of assuming that there was not value, but there was a value of zero.

After that, I broke down the sum(if(...)) expression.  it turns out that when I used

```
=SUM(iif(Fields!SOPTYPE.Value = 3, Fields!QUANTITY.Value, 0))
```

I received data, but when I used

```
=SUM(iif(Fields!DOCID.Value = "INV", Fields!QUANTITY.Value, 0))
```

I got a warning message:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State    
Warning     [rsAggregateOfMixedDataTypes] The Y expression for the chart ‘Chart7’ 
uses an aggregate function on data of varying data types.  Aggregate functions other than 
First, Last, Previous, Count, and CountDistinct can only aggregate data of a single data type.
```

After doing some internet searches, it was getting an error due to the return data type in Quantity.  So I just updated the sum(if(...)) expression to return a CInt.  And this fixed the problem.

Updated expression:

```
=SUM(iif(Fields!SOPTYPE.Value = 3 AND Fields!DOCID.Value = "INV" 
OR Fields!DOCID.Value = "RMAINV", CInt(Fields!QUANTITY.Value), 0))
```

But I'm still not sure how one field is returning varying data types, unless the 0 I used for the else portion of the iif is a different data type from the value field.

Comment: You can use `Nothing` instead of a 0 to avoid data type issues.